# How can I call a classes's other function inside a http request callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, asynchronous

I have a function that makes an HTTP GET request. It is a member function of my "CheckPrice" class. When I try to call another function that belongs to that class in the callback, it says that it is undefined. What should I do?

```
const got = require("got")


class PriceCheck {

    constructor() {
        this.lastTick;
        this.requestTimerHandle
    }

    /**
     * 
     * get the absolute percent difference between two numbers
     * 
     * @param {*} firstNum 
     * @param {*} secondNum 
     * @returns 
     */
     absolutePercentDiff(firstNum, secondNum) {

        return ( Math.abs(firstNum - secondNum) / ((firstNum + secondNum) /2) ) * 100
    }

    /**
     * send message to standard out if price difference too high
     * 
     * @param {*} currentTick 
     * @param {*} threshold - a percent  
     */
     alertDifference(currentTick, threshold) {

        if (this.lastTick != undefined) {

            let lastPrice = Number(lastTick.ask);
            let currentPrice = Number(currentTick.ask);

            let diff = this.absolutePercentDiff(lastPrice, currentPrice);

        if (diff >= threshold) {
            console.log("ALERT: price changed " + diff + " percent")
        } 
        }

        this.lastTick = currentTick;
    }
    
    /**
     * 
     * @param {*} first first currency
     * @param {*} second second currency
     * @param {*} threshold % difference in prices from last retreival to send alert
     * @param {*} interval how long to wait before retreiving price again
     */
    requestRateInterval = function(first, second, threshold, interval) {
        if (typeof this.requestTimerHandle != 'undefined') {
            clearInterval(requestTimerHandle)
        }
        this.requestTimerHandle = setInterval(this.requestRate, interval, first, second, threshold)
    }

    async requestRate(first, second, threshold) {
        console.log("requesting conversion rate between " + first + " and " + second)
        
        try {
            const response = await got('https://company.com/api' + first + '-' + second);
            console.log(response.body);
            let currentTick = JSON.parse(response.body);
            this.alertDifference(currentTick, threshold);

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.response.body);
        }
    }

}

module.exports = {PriceCheck: PriceCheck}
```

The output is:

(node:1282) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined

In my app.js:

```
priceChecker = new PriceCheck();
priceChecker.requestRateInterval("BTC", "USD", 0.01, 5000);
```

Comment: how is `alertDifference` defined? are you binding `requestRate` in your constructor?

Comment: it is defined as a regular function in the class. What do you mean binding it in the constructor?

Comment: https://cmichel.io/es6-class-methods-differences/

Comment: It is defined the standard way i.e. not instance-specific

Comment: then you need to bind it in the constructor so `this` has the proper value when you access it in other instance methods

Comment: I added `this.alertDifference = this.alertDifference.bind(this)` to the constructor and it still says `this.alertDifference is not a function`

Comment: please post your entire class and how you're using it.

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232929/discussion-between-ben-r-and-derek).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor you must [bind your instance methods](https://cmichel.io/es6-class-methods-differences/) so `this` has a value within the context of that instance method like so:

```
constructor() {
    this.lastTick;
    this.requestTimerHandle;

    // Bound instance methods
    this.absolutePercentDiff = this.absolutePercentDiff.bind(this);
    this.alertDifference = this.alertDifference.bind(this);
    this.requestRateInterval = this.requestRateInterval.bind(this);
    this.requestRate = this.requestRate.bind(this);
}
```

Otherwise, `this` is undefined within the context of your instance method.